# Change The index of a comboBox in windows Application in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i have 100 objects of areas which have id and name i want to show name in combobox and their id's as index of combobox but this code is not working

```
private void Areadropdown()//show Areadropdown
    {
        List<Area> list = Area.Dropdown();


        foreach (Area a in list)
        {

          metroComboBox1.Items.Insert(a.Id,a.Areaname);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<Area> list = new  List<Area>();

 metroComboBox1.DisplayMember = "PropertyName" //for you want to display in dropdown so give that class property name
 metroComboBox1.ValueMember = "ProprtyName" // use for take  value of those selection 

  metroComboBox1.DataSource = list; //your data list

this code help to solve your problem
```

FYI 
Please refereed below example

```
  districtComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
  districtComboBox.ValueMember = "Id";
  districtComboBox.DataSource = districts.Where(d => d.StateId == (int)stateComboBox.SelectedValue).ToList()
```

Comment: but its value members are again generic like 0,1,2,3,4...

Comment: @UmairAhmad so what you wan't to display instead of this 0,1,2,3,4 ??

Comment: like area grain market have id 4000 and rise markey have id 5000 i need these id's as value member or index number

Comment: @UmairAhmad In your arealist you are pass grain market with 4000 id so it's working like charm do this for all other

Comment: Area list have objects of all areas.How i Can bind Them..?

Answer (score 0):

try this

User the name of properties defined in class as display member and membervalue

```
districtComboBox.DisplayMember = "Areaname";
districtComboBox.ValueMember = "Id";
```

Comment: But this is not work properly still my problem was not sloved

Comment: @UmairAhmad can you explain more in detail what you need

Answer (score 0):

Try this (using BindingList) :

```
private void Areadropdown()
{
  List<Area> list = Area.Dropdown();
  BindingList<Area> areas = new BindingList<Area>(list); 
  metroComboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
  metroComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Areaname";
  metroComboBox1.DataSource = areas ;
}
```

Comment: But its value members are again index numbers like 0,1,2,3,4.